# Find Differences in a Database After an Insert

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a program that interacts with a database. When the program interacts with the database, all is fine. However, I need to add functionality to the program that modifies the database.

The database I inherited. None of the tables or columns have logical names. Even if the names did mean something, the documentation on them has been lost long ago. I am trying to insert/delete an item into the database, and it seems to corrupt it every time.

What I would like to do is somehow save the state of the database before the insert/delete, insert/delete into the database, and then save the state of the database after the insert/delete. By doing this, I can then see exactly what tables are being updated, and with what values. I can then make an honest attempt at trying to modify the application to use the database.

Are there any tools out there that exist to do this? Is this even possible? Is there another way I could achieve my goal?

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using? Enterprise?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a trace with SQL Profiler?  Seems like that would be the first place to start.  Execute the action in the application and trace what happens.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be a trigger is on the table you are inserting to.

You should run profiler though and see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Create&Insert to make a backup of every table affected before modifying your database (if you only need the backups for a short time, temporary tables or a table variable could work).  Then you'd have to make a query that compares the before&after.

If your recordsets are small enough, and you're doing this manually, a copy&paste to Excel might be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that you should start with SQL Profiler. If you set the criteria properly, you should easily see what actions are performed during the insert and delete commands that end in corruption.